# Genius easypen i405x tablet not recognized in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, usb, graphics-tablet

I tried to get genius easypen i405x to work on the latest ubuntu but the input is not responding. I installed the digimend drivers and lsusb returns:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0458:5010 KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) EasyPen i405X
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1199:9079 Sierra Wireless, Inc. Sierra Wireless EM7455 Qualcomm Snapdragon X7 LTE-A
```

Howerver xinput and evtest are not showing it:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Could anyone suggest what I could do here?

Comment: FYI 20.04 is not the latest Ubuntu version depending on what version you look at LTS etc..